# Update windows registry using java invoked by a windows service of SYSTEM account

Tags: java, windows, windows-services, registry

I am trying to update the windows registry as a service having SYSTEM privileges.
If I update the registry using Java it works fine since the Java uses the Administrator account.
When I try to update the registry using Java invoked by a windows service using SYSTEM account it does not update anything.

How do I provide the access to the SYSTEM account to update the registry.

Working in pure Java, not working if it invoked by a service of SYSTEM account.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to set some privileges for your logon access token. We run a Java service under windows and I always set some privileges before I access the registry like the following:

```
public static final String BACKUP_PRIV = "SeBackupPrivilege";    
public static final String RESTORE_PRIV = "SeRestorePrivilege";  
public static final String SECURITY_PRIV = "SeSecurityPrivilege";
```

If I don't set these it won't work. There may be more fine grained privileges that you can set but I'm not sure what they will be.

We had to write some native code to do this for us, making use of Win API functions like the following:

- [OpenProcessToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [LookupPrivilegeValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [AdjustTokenPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)